# What is the difference between 3 Phase volt drop and Impedence ratings for 4 core cables?

Tags: cables

Looking at ratings given for some cables, there is a 3-phase Volt Drop given in milli Volts/Amps/meter, and there is an impedance rating given in Ohms/kilometer. These 2 units are equivalent, but the values vary quite a bit. If we have that V = I * Z, why is the impedance value different from this volt drop value? I have attached ratings for a cable below.
[image: Standard Cable Ratings]

Answer (score 1):

I see now that the Volt Drop is a Line-Line voltage. Calculating Volt Drop with impedance gives you a Line-Neutral Voltage.